# First deriative, multiplied by first derivative

Tags: calculus, partial-differential-equations

I have one question. If I multiply 2 first deriatives, will I receive second derivative? Example:
$$\frac{\partial a}{\partial t} = \dot{a}$$
Is it true?:
$$\frac{\partial\dot{a}}{\partial t}=\ddot{a}$$

Comment: You are taking the derivative again, not multiplying by it. However, $\frac{d}{dx}y' = y''$ is correct.

Comment: Oh, I'm sorry. But, thanks, It's solved my problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Imagine $f(x)=x^2$, then we have that $f'(x)=2x$ and

$$ 2=f''(x)\neq\left(f'(x)\right)^2=4x^2$$

Answer (score 1):

No, equality does not hold in general:
$$
f''(x):=\lim_{h \to 0}\frac{f'(x+h)-f'(x)}{h} \neq \left(\lim_{h \to 0}\frac{f(x+h)-f(x)}{h}\right)^2=f'(x)^2 \, .
$$